# What are the common patterns about logging of Glassfish applications?

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, logback

I am building a simple REST service application, which will be deployed to Glassfish. I am currently using `logback` for the application with a `logback.xml`, and one dependency artifact also uses `logback` and has its own `logback.xml`. So, one question I am having, which is not necessarily related to `Glassfish`, is how the two `logback.xml`'s are utilized by `logback`? Is only the application one used or the dependency one also used?

Another question I am having, which is related to `Glassfish`, is whether logs from the application will be merged to `glassfish/domains/<domain-dir(mine is domain1)>/logs/server.log` no matter what? I have `FileAppender` appenders in the application `logback.xml` with relative file paths. So, what is the parent path of those relative file paths? For example, given the following configuration:

```
<appender name="FILE-PROFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/profile.txt</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

where is the `logs/profile.txt` located?

As you can see, the questions above are very specific questions, whereas the title of this post is kind of asking a general question. The reason for this situation is that I probably wouldn't ask those specific questions if I had known common patterns about logging of Glassfish applications. So, my ultimate question is, what is your experience about logging of Glassfish applications, and what is your reason for your approach? In particular, how do you approach the situation that the Glassfish itself (`java.util.logging`), your application, and your application dependencies use different logging framework? I like `logback`, but I don't know if it is a norm for Glassfish applications to use `java.util.logging`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that your web application cannot access the file system directly and still be Java EE compliant.  Hence you cannot use logback and log to a file.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1 :how the two logback.xml's are utilized by logback ?**

**Ans :** By default, logback pick "logback.xml" file from the classpath, So I believe your both logback.xml will be at different location so you won't get any issue. Just make sure logback.xml for slf4j logback should be under your application classpath.

Or

If you want you can place logback.xml file of slf4j logback under some config directory and override logback's default configuration. check [here](https://github.com/abdulwaheed18/Slf4jTutorial/blob/master/src/com/waheed/tutorial5/Application5.java) for more detials.

**Q2 : where is the logs/profile.txt located?**

I have never used glassfish server but I tried the same thing on tomcat and I always find my logs under tomcat directory, So I believe your logs also get created somewhere under $glassfish/logs/profile.txt.

**Ans 3:** Yes, you can use slf4j logback in your application as it provides many more features than "java.util.logging" and in future you can logs all the glassfish logs under your log by just adding one dependency jars.